# Prove the following are equivalent with irreducibility of representation on $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\pi: A \to B(\mathcal{H})$ be a representation where $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra and $\mathcal{H}$ a Hilbert space. I'm trying to show the following four statements are equivalent:

(1) $\pi$ is irreducible.

(2) $\pi(A)' = \mathbb{C}1_{\mathcal{H}}$.

(3) $\pi(A)'$ contains no non-trivial projections.

(4) Every $h \in \mathcal{H}\setminus \{0\}$ is a cyclic vector for $\pi$.

I managed to show $(1) \implies (4)$ and $(2) \implies (3)$ and $(1) \implies (2)$ but I'm stuck on the other implications. I read other answers but most of these use Von Neumann Algebra theory, from which I know nothing, so please avoid using Von Neumann algebra facts to answer this question.

Comment: (3)$\implies$(1) follows from noting that if $H=V \oplus V'$ is a decomposition into subrepresentations then you can use self-adjointness of $\pi(A)$ to see that $V'=V^\perp$. Then the projection onto $V$ (or $V'$) commutes with every element of $\pi(A)$, meaning $V$ is $H$ or $0$. The implication (4)$\implies$(1) is similar. If $H=V\oplus V'$ is a decomposition into subrepresentations then since $V$ is invariant it can only have non-zero cyclic vectors if $V$ is all of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

For the missing implication (3) $\Rightarrow$ (4), prove the counter-reciprocal. If there is a non-zero vector $h \in H$ such that it is not cyclic, then $\pi(A)'$ has a nontrivial projection. Let $K = \overline{\pi(A)h}$ be the cyclic subspace generated by $h$. It is non-null since $h \neq 0$ and standard approximate unit arguments and it is not $H$. Elementary calculations give that the projection $P_K \in B(H)$ belongs to $\pi(A)'$.